# Getting value out of text field

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get data out of my text field. As the text field is linked to the contents of my database, it always returns me the value of {{activities.Url}} instead of the actual value. As i'm trying to get the value to be stored in a variable and then the call out a function, my function wouldn't work as the values will always be {{activities.url}} instead of the actual url. Any way I can get the actual value?

Activities.html:

```
 <input type="text" id="videourl1" ng-controller="activitesCtrl" value='{{activities1.url}}' enabled/>
```

Controller.js:

```
var url1 = document.getElementById("videourl1").value;
var myurl = getId(url1);
console.log(url1);
```

Comment: Why not just use `ng-model`?  Do you need the value outside of your `ng-controller`?

Comment: No I don't. I've been trying different ways to get data out of the value. So I tried adding different things and see if i can get the actual value instead of the {{activities1.url}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. You need $scope in the controller in order to access it dynamically. The console log in the if statement can be replaced with whatever functionality you want to use the $scope.activities1 information.

```
<script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('activitiesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.activities1 = 'www.exampleurl.com';
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.activities1) {
          console.log($scope.activities1)
          $scope.activities = '';
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="activitiesCtrl">
  Enter url and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="activities1" name="url" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>url={{activities1}}</pre>
</form>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: But this is more like a manual input from a text field. What I was planning to do was make the text field hidden. As the data is retrieved from the database, I will get the value out to a variable and call my method to convert urls to embed urls.

Comment: In that case, `$scope.activities1 = urlFromDatabase`.  If you want to just show it on the page wrap `{{activities1}}` inside of a div that point to your controller.

    <div ng-controller='activitiesCtrl'>
    <a href={{activities1}}>Click here</a>
    </div>